# Has the way to access public member variables in solidity through deployed contracts changed?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a public contract member defined like this, which is later assigned a value in the constructor

```
AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
```

I want to access this variable's value and I am trying like this

```
fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer);
const response = await fundMe.priceFeed();
```

But I am getting error:

```
Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method": "priceFeed", "signature": "priceFeed()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.7.1)
```

I am getting this error when I am running the test which is defined below

```js
const { assert } = require("chai");
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");

describe("FundMe", async () => {
  let fundMe;
  let deployer;
  let MockV3Aggregator;
  beforeEach(async function () {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
    await deployments.fixture("all");
    fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer); // <-- change to getContract
    MockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt("MockV3Aggregator", deployer); // <-- same change here
  });

  describe("constructor", async function () {
    it("Sets the aggregator address correctly", async function () {
      const response = await fundMe.priceFeed(); //<-- error here
      console.log(response);

      assert.equal(response, MockV3Aggregator.target);
    });
  });
});
```

The fundMe contract is

```
contract FundMe {

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;

    constructor(address customPriceFeed) {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(customPriceFeed);
    }
```

hardhat.config.js file :

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
require("./tasks/block-number");
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers"); // <-- error solved by adding this

const SEPOLIA_URL = process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL || "https://sepolia.com";
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "key";
const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || "key";

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.8.19",
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.6",
      },
    ],
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: true,
    outputFile: "gas-reporter.txt",
    noColors: true,
    currency: "INR",
    coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  },
  namedAccounts: {
    deployer: {
      default: 0,
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: This contract interface `AggregatorV3Interface` is for chainlink price feeds. The deployment process should differ when deploying on the dev chain (hardhat and local host) from deploying to testnets like Sepolia. Could you provide the deploying js script?

Comment: probably your interface is not aware of type `AggregatorV3Interface`. you could try changing that to return an address instead, then `getContractAt("AggregatorV3Interface", fundMe.callStatic.priceFeed())`

Comment: @Al-Qa'qa' I am deploying the contracts on hardhat default network and I have two deploy scripts one for mocks and other for contract. I have edited and added the deploy scripts.

Comment: Try to change `getContractAt` into `getContract`, and change `MockV3Aggregator.target` into `MockV3Aggregator.address` in the test script, and see if the error disappeared or not.

Comment: @Al-Qa'qa' Thanks! I was able to run the function `getContract()` by importing `require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");` in **hardhat.config.js** file. Although I couldn't understand how it worked out?! Because when I imported ethers package in my test.js file `const { ethers } = require("hardhat");` then it was showing error `ethers.getContract` function is not a function, but after requiring the package @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers in my hardhat.config.js file, I was able to call the function. Can anybody tell how they are related. It would be really helpful.

Comment: `hardhat` framework adds some functions to `ethersjs` lib, so you need to import ethers from hardhat in the hardhat config file to add hardhat external functions to ethers. there are some plugins that you can add to your hardhat framework such as `hardhat-deploy` that you added. the normal ethers lib you import from hardhat don't have `getContract` function, this function comes from `hardhat-deploy`, so after importing the `hardhat-ethers` and `hardhat-deploy` the function becomes accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change `getContractAt` by `getContract`
- in testing use `MockV3Aggregator.address` instead of `MockV3Aggregator.target`

Don't forget to import the hardhat ethers, and hardhat deploy modules in **hardhat config file**, this part was added in the question itself.

```
// hardhat.config.js
require("hardhat-deploy");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
```